# Best way to automatically redirect to a website

Tags: http, redirect

We have several sites which we need to automatically redirect to another site. At the moment we use index.html with following content to do the redirection (sorry about the tags):

```
<html>  
  <head>  
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.example.com" /> 
  </head>
</html>
```

Is there a better way to do automatic redirection? Maybe programatically with 301? We can not use .htaccess, or something like that. We use asp.net and php on those sites which are being redirected.

Cheers

Comment: click the "code" button (101010) in the editor toolbar, or indent each code line by 4 spaces and you can use HTML tags freely ;)

Comment: Thanks Jon, I didn't quite get the indent stuff :)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP

```
<?php
// 302 redirect
header('Location: newpage.html', TRUE, 302);
?>
```

Comment: Do you know, maybe, how to do it in .net?

Answer (score 0):

using php, you can set Location in header instead

header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this client-side in javascript

```
window.location="http://www.domain.com"
```